# Which option of ls should be used for understanding metadata changes?

Tags: ls

How can one find the latest time of metadata changes to a file?

Let's say I changed the ownership of a file and then I did `ls -l`. It still shows the latest file changes. But I want to see the time that I changed the ownership.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be:

```
ls -lc
```

`-c` reports the `ctime` which is the inode change time. That's updated every time the file metadata (excluding `atime` modifications resulting from reading the file) or data is modified, and contrary to `utime` or `atime` can't be arbitrarily set.